# Deploy angular and core web api in single solution to single azure web app

Tags: angular, api, .net-core, azure-web-app-service, visual-studio-2022

How can we deploy both angular and api projects(6.0) in single solution to single azure web app? In Visual studio 2022, we have stand alone angular template option to create an angular project. If I am adding a .net 6 api also to this same solution, how can we deploy both in single web app?

Comment: Could you please share the code which you have tried ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-angular?view=vs-2022 is the link I followed to create this.

Comment: Are you getting any error ?

Comment: Unable to find project information for .es project error is coming while building api project after adding reference to angular project.

Answer (score 2):

Check the below steps to deploy `.NETCORE 6 Web API` and `Angular` Application into the same Azure App Service.

- In VS, Create a blank project and name it as `AngularAPI`.
  [image]
- In the blank project, Add the new Project `.Net CORE Web API` and name it as `CoreAPI`.
  [image]
- Add another project with name `Angular` and delete all the folders except `Dependencies` and `Connected Services`.
  [image]
- Now in the project named `Angular` we need to add and configure the Angular components.
- Open the command prompt, navigate to the `Angular` folder and run the below command to create `new angular app`.

```cs
ng new angapp
```

[image]

- Navigate to the newly created `angapp` folder  and run the below command.

```cs
ng serve --open
```

- Open `angular.json` file and change the `output` path to
  `"outputPath": "../../CoreAPI/wwwroot"`.
- In command prompt, Run  `ng build`.
  [image]
- `wwwroot` folder will be created in `CoreAPI` project folder.
  [image]
- In .NetCore WebAPI App, add the below lines of code in `Program.cs` file.

```cs
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    await next();
    if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 && !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value))
    {
        context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
        await next();
    }
});
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

- Set `CoreAPI` as Startup project. Run the app locally. Able to run both Angular and .Net Core API in the same port.
  [image]
  [image]
- Right click on the `CoreAPI` (.NetCore Web API App) folder and click on `Publish` to deploy the Application to `Azure App Service`.
  [image]

***Output of Deployed Azure App :***

[image]