# web or app config in an App Service to handle Angular routing

Tags: azure

I'm running an Angular app and a .NET Core API on an App Service. I need to update the web.config to handle refreshing as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68103523/386869).

But my app doesn't have a web.config as it is, and when I tried to add one in the Angular app, publishing failed. Is there a way to modify the web.config through the Azure portal, or another way to accomplish the above?

[The code repo](https://github.com/rarDevelopment/rardk-web-dotnet) if that helps.

Comment: Are you deploying to Azure `Windows` or `Linux` App Service ?

Comment: How you are deploying your Application ?

Comment: Deploying to a Windows App Service on Azure via Visual Studio's Publish tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried to run your given repo in my local, I got the below warning.

[image]

- If you want to add the `Web.config` file to Angular App before deploying to `Azure App service`, then follow the below steps.
- Open the `Angular` Application root directory.
- Add the `web.config` file in the `src` root directory.
- Open the Package manager console and run `ng build`.

```js
npm install
npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
ng build
```

- A new folder with name `dist` will be created.
  Now re-deploy the app again.

> Is there a way to modify the web.config through the Azure portal.

If you have deployed your application to `Azure Windows App Service`, then we can create the `web.config` file within the deployed Application Angular root directory from `KUDU` Console.

Open the KUDU console by using the below `URL`,

```cs
https://YourAppServiceName.scm.azurewebsites.net/
```

[image]

[image]

- Make sure you are creating `webconfig` file in the `Angular Application` root directory.
- If your application is deployed in `Azure Linux App Service`, then you need to create `.htaccess` file as mentioned in the [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45072185/angular-deployment-404-on-page-refresh/68103523#68103523) which you have shared.

To deploy the `Angular app` and `.NET Core API` to `Azure App service`without any issues, follow the SO Thread [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74724437/using-net-core-angular-template-how-to-access-api-once-deployed-to-azure/74726900#74726900) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74274213/deploy-angular-and-core-web-api-in-single-solution-to-single-azure-web-app/74473563#74473563) for more details.

Comment: The part I was missing seems to have been the `app.Use...` section in the Program.cs file